# Email failed to receive in mail

Tags: java

It is showing as mail has successfully sent and shown in server logs as below. But could not receive any mail.

```
 From: no-reply@xyz.com 
 To: abc@xyz.com, xyz123@xyz.com 
 Message-ID: <122809963.2.1560151439967.JavaMail.Desktop@DESKTOP-KNFEDPS> 
 Subject: =?Cp1252?Q? 
 MIME-Version: 1.0 
 Content-Type: multipart/mixed;     
 boundary="----=_Part_0_1750030278.1560151406255"
```

> ------=_Part_0_1750030278.1560151406255

Content-Type: multipart/related;
 boundary="----=_Part_1_691751421.1560151406281"

> ------=_Part_1_691751421.1560151406281 
>        Content-Type: text/html; 
>        charset=us-ascii 
>        Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
 <html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
    <head>  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />  
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
    </head>  
    <body style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none; box-sizing: border-box; color: #74787E; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica  Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; height: 100%; line-height: 1.4; margin:  0; width: 100% !important;" bgcolor="#F2F4F6">  
        <table class="email-wrapper" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="box-sizing: border-box; font-family: Arial,  'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0; width:  100%;" bgcolor="#F2F4F6">  
             ....... ........  
        </table>  
    </body>
 </html>
```

> ------=_Part_1_691751421.1560151406281--
>
> ------=_Part_0_1750030278.1560151406255-- . 250 OK queued as ec39e76e-81cb-41b4-90f7-028a7ed23005 QUIT 221 2.0.0 Bye

Comment: Please share the code and stacktrace. Hope you are using Java Mail API latest. which version ?

Comment: Is this a java question or a mail/network related question?

Answer (score 0):

Here your email is not sent yet, As per your log it is written that it is in the queue right now. you may need to wait until receiving an email.

I've posted below the line from your log which helps you to understand what server log wants you to say.

> OK queued as ec39e76e-81cb-41b4-90f7-028a7ed23005 QUIT 221 2.0.0 Bye